# No implicit format for MyClass available using Json.format

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, implicit

I'm getting an error when using a complex object as attribute of another object on Json.format.

I have two classes: **RoleDTO** and **EmailInvitationDTO**. **EmailInvitationDTO** has a **RoleDTO**. So, I declared:

```
case class RoleDTO(id:Option[Long] = None, roleType:Int, userID:Long, fromHousingUnitID:Option[Long] = None, isAdmin:Option[Boolean] = None, fromResidentUserID:Option[Long] = None, documentNumber:Option[String] = None, fromCondoID:Option[Long] = None)
object RoleDTO { val roleFormat = Json.format[RoleDTO] }

case class EmailInvitationDTO(firstName:String, lastName:String, email:String, role:RoleDTO)
object EmailInvitationDTO{ val emailInvitationFormat = Json.format[EmailInvitationDTO] }
```

I'm getting the error: No implicit format for **RoleDTO** available. Even if I declare the ***roleFormat*** variable in a line before ***emailInvitationFormat***:

```
object EmailInvitationDTO {
    val roleFormat = Json.format[RoleDTO]
    val emailInvitationFormat = Json.format[EmailInvitationDTO]
}
```

Anyone knows what is missing? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if we knew what these classes looked like.

Comment: edited the question with more info.

Comment: You need to make `roleFormat` and `emailInvitationFormat` implicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include an implicit `roleFormat` in your `EmailInvitationDTO` object declaration.  The `Json.format` macro looks for implicit Json formats at compile time, otherwise it will have no idea how to read/write the `RoleDTO` in your `EmailInvitationDTO`.

So you'll need the following line in scope before creating an `emailInvitationFormat`:

```
implicit val roleFormat = Json.format[RoleDTO]
```

Comment: i did it, the error is still happening(see the edit).

Comment: oh, got it now. I forgot the implicit identifier. sorry, buddy.

Comment: Found this while trying to solve a different problem, but the post gave me a hint of what was wrong with my code, so in case someone else runs into the same issue as me, it's worth pointing out that the implicits need to be declared in the right order, so RoleDto needs to come before EmailInvocationDto.