# No implicit format for MyClass available using Json.format - Composed of object of same type

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, implicit

I have a **Category** Class which is composed of a parent category of type **Category** itself.

```
case class Category (name: String,
                 description: String,
                  categoryParent: Category)
```

I am getting an error: No Implicit format for Category available.

```
object CategoryFormat {
 implicit val categoryParentFormat = Json.format[Category]
 val categoryFormat = Json.format[Category]
}
```

I have also referred this post with similar question: 
[No implicit format for MyClass available using Json.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676421/no-implicit-format-for-myclass-available-using-json-format)

Am I missing something? Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Granted that you are not using `null`, can you show me how are you going to instantiate a class with a cyclic reference to itself?

Comment: It can be null if the parent is itself. Say for instance you have Computer Sicence, Mathematics and Probability as categories. For probability -> Mathematics is the parent and for Mathematics -> Computer Science is the parent. So Computer Science will be root of the tree which will have no parent category. Given a requirement like this how can the model be designed. @EndeNeu

Comment: If the macro doesn't work, you'll have to create the Format yourself using `lazyFormat`.

Comment: @Kaushik how to model the problem is a different question and probably should be asked elsewhere, what I wanted to point out (at least from what you shared in your question) is that unless you use `null` you can't possibly instantiate a `Category` because every one of them takes another `Category` and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: As @MariusSoutier mentioned you should try to define this with lazy val. I am investigation for similar issues. The play! documentation mentions a solution to your problem under [_Recursive Types_.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators)